# How can I set the value of TBScertificate::signiture during I generate a X509cert with java?

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate

I'm going to generate a cert and set this value:

```
TBSCertificate::=SEQUENCE{
version           [0]   EXPLICIT Version DEFAULT v1,
serialNumber            CertificateSerialNumber,
signature               AlgorithmIdentifier,***<---this one*** 
issuer                  Name,
validity                Validity,
subject                 Name,
subjectPublicKeyInfo    SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
issuerUniqueID    [1]   IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
subjectUniqueID   [2]   IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
extensions        [3]   EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
}
```

this is my code，right now I can only set SerialNumber，IssuerDN，NotBefore，NotAfter，SubjectDN，PublicKey，SignatureAlgorithm，:

```
public X509Certificate generateCert(String[] info, KeyPair keyPair_root,KeyPair keyPair_user) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, SecurityException, SignatureException {
    X509V3CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
    X509Certificate cert = null;
    certGen.setSerialNumber(new BigInteger(info[8]));
    certGen.setIssuerDN(new X509Name(
            "CN=huahua, OU=hnu, O=university , C=china"));
    certGen.setNotBefore(new Date(Long.parseLong(info[6])));
    certGen.setNotAfter(new Date(Long.parseLong(info[7])));
    certGen.setSubjectDN(new X509Name("C=" + info[0] + ",OU=" + info[1]
            + ",O=" + info[2] + ",C=" + info[3] + ",L=" + info[4] + ",ST="
            + info[3]));
    certGen.setPublicKey(keyPair_user.getPublic());
    certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1WithRSA");
    cert = certGen.generateX509Certificate(keyPair_root.getPrivate(), "BC");
    return cert;
}
```

I will be appreciate it if any one could help me!I have find many solutions but none of them can help me.

Comment: It makes no sense to use both `info[0]` and `info[3]` for `C=` (Country); I bet the first one should be `CN=` (CommonName).

Answer (score 1):

`TBSCertificate.signature` is named poorly, it isn't a signature, just the signature algorithm identifier.

This value is presumably controlled by `certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm(...)`, which you're already using.

Comment: Will it be shown in the certificate?